# How to check user in a linux group using .net core 2.1 or above?

Tags: .net-core

How to check if a user belongs to a Linux group? i.e. I wish to allow my app for user in the same group to run.

Answer (score -1):

Use command

```
dotnet --verion
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21

Comment: Sorry but I am asking how to check if a user in a group programmatically using .net core 2.1 code..